# Why does Hatcher mention relative homology (Proof of Euler Characteristic)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I refer to Hatcher's proof of Euler Characteristic. I don't understand why Hatcher mentions relative homology $C_n=H_n(X^n, X^{n-1})$.

I thought that once we prove that $\sum_n (-1)^n \text{rank}\, (C_n)=\sum_n (-1)^n \text{rank}\, H_n$, we are basically done with the proof? Since $\text{rank}\, C_n$ is the number of $n$-cells of $X$?

I may have missed an important point, thanks for any enlightenment.

Hatcher (pg 146):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because it is the relative $n$-homology, not the free abelian group on the $n$-cells, which is the definition of the cellular $n$-chains, perhaps? (Note the difference between capital $C_n$ and lower-case $c_n$.)

Comment: In more detail, cellular homology is isomorphic to singular. On the other hand, the rank of the cellular chains $C_n=H_n(X_n,X_{n-1})$ is precisely the number of $n$-cells attached to the $(n-1)$-skeleton. Thus $\sum (-1)^n {\rm rank} C_n$ is the Euler characteristic.

Comment: @Arthur $H_n(X_n,X_{n-1})$ can be identified with the free abelian group on the $n$-cells. This is not hard to show -- pass to reduced homology and you will end up computing the $n$-homology of a wedge of $n$-spheres, one for each generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the very last line of the proof for the moment, what this proof demonstrates is an abstract statement in algebra that a priori has nothing whatsoever to do with $X$ or its cells, namely: for any chain complex $(C_n)$ with corresponding homology groups $(H_n)$, 
$$\sum_n (-1)^n \text{rank}(C_n) = \sum_n (-1)^n \text{rank} H_n
$$
Having proved this equation, you are still very far from done, because you have proved nothing about $X$ yet. All you have proved is an abstract lemma in homological algebra.

To bring the CW complex $X$ into the picture, the idea is that there is a cellular chain complex with the following properties: its $n$th homology group is isomorphic to the absolute singular homology group $H_n(X)$; its $n$th chain group $C_n$ *is* the relative singular homology group $H_n(X_n,X_{n-1})$; and $\text{rank}(C_n) = \text{rank}(H_n(X_n,X_{n-1}))$ is equal to the number of $n$ cells. NOW you have proved something about $X$!